# Micronaut Http Client Using a Map for Query Parameters

Tags: micronaut-client

While defining a client interface is there a way to pass a map of Query parameters?   I know I can do a single via:

```
@Client("MyApi)
interface Zoo { 

  fun fetchAnimals(@QueryValue color : String) : String 
  
}
```

But, how would a add a variable map of parameters?

```
@Client
interface Zoo { 

  fun fetchAnimals(@QueryMap color : Map<String,String>) : String 
  
}
```

@QueryMap is from retrofit but I can't figure out an equivalent in micronaut or another workaround?

Answer (score 1):

[6.4 Simple Request Binding : Binding from Multiple Query values](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/#binding)

> Binding from Multiple Query values
> Instead of binding from a single section of the request, it may be desirable to bind all query values for example to a POJO. This can be achieved by using the exploded operator (?pojo*) in the URI template.

For example:

```kotlin
@Client("/")
interface Zoo { 

  @Get("{?colors*}")
  fun fetchAnimals(@QueryValue colors : Map<String,Any>) : String 
  
}
```